# Counting the order of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

**Consider this problem:**

*A connected graph has the same number of vertices of degree 1 and 4. There is 1 vertex of degree 8, and no vertices of any other degree. The graph has size 24. Determine the order of the graph.*

---

**My attempt:**

Since there's a vertex of degree $8$, there's at least $9$ vertices. Since a graph must have even number of odd vertices, and the number of vertex with degree $1$ is the same as the number of vertex of degree $4$, the size of $G = 9, 13, 17, ...$, hence it must increase $4$ at a time.

Since we already have a vertex of degree $8$, we can eliminate the possibility of $|G| > 25$, since $|G| = 25$ represents the case when the graph is minimally connected.

We have a pool of $\{9, 13, 17, 21, 25\}$. $25$ is impossible since it's when $G$ is minimal, so our pool is $\{9, 13, 17, 21\}$

---

**Struggle:**

From this point on I can't think of a better way to do this other than trying to brute force everything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

A more general arithmetic/approach that solves this types of problems (if it exists) would be even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Handshaking Lemma, the sum of the vertex degrees is twice the number of edges. Suppose there are $k$ vertices of degree $1$. So:

$$k(1 + 4) + 8 = 24 \cdot 2$$

Thus, $5k = 40$, so $k = 8$. Thus, there are $8$ vertices of degree $1$, $8$ vertices of degree $4$, and $1$ vertex of degree $8$.

So $|G| = 17$.

Comment: Nice and concise. Thanks.